# Where do you store your gitconfig file?

Tags: git

Any great tips on storing a gitconfig file somewhere where it can easily be replicated when SSH'ing into another Linux computer or otherwise using another computer?

Comment: I just use `scp` (http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=scp&sektion=1) when I'm sshing. I try to keep most of my config files on github as well so I can access them if I'm not on my computer.

Comment: rsync may be better than scp

Comment: I store all the config files (including gitconfig) from home as git repository

Comment: This question is largely opinion-based and is probably off-topic for stackoverflow. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for advice on how to keep your questions on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I use a git repository containing my configuration files and preferences designed to be used [GNU `stow`](https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/).

> GNU Stow is a symlink farm manager which takes distinct packages of
>   software and/or data located in separate directories on the
>   filesystem, and makes them appear to be installed in the same place.
>   For example, /usr/local/bin could contain symlinks to files within
>   /usr/local/stow/emacs/bin, /usr/local/stow/perl/bin etc., and likewise
>   recursively for any other subdirectories such as .../share, .../man,
>   and so on.
>
> This is particularly useful for keeping track of system-wide and
>   per-user installations of software built from source, but can also
>   facilitate a more controlled approach to management of configuration
>   files in the user's home directory, especially when coupled with
>   version control systems.

Thus, on all of my computers, `$HOME/.gitconfig` is actually just a simlink to `$HOME/dotfiles/git/.gitconfig`, and installation, once the `dotfiles` repository is cloned from my server, consists of just `cd`ing to the repository and running `stow git`. Changes can be made and shared easily by editing the config file normally or through `git config`, then committing in the repository, and then pulling from other sources.

Comment: +1. Being able to just `git clone`, and push-and-pull changes will save you so much time. Paired with https://github.com/, this is doubly true. (And how I manage my dotfiles.) Open source your dotfiles — there's little point not to: you'll never make money off them, and others can learn from you (and you from others: search, there's a lot already out there. It's a good way to find tricks others use.)

Comment: I absolutely agree with open sourcing them, but just remember not to do it if you keep passwords in your repository. I use `fetchmail` to retrieve my mail, and keep the password-containing config file in my dotfiles repository, so I have to be a little careful with where I store it, but my use case is probably a little unusual.

Comment: Thanks @SashaCrofter. Do you also store your Vim/text editor dot files in a similar manner? I will be picking your answer as best shortly.

Comment: Yes, I keep `.vimrc` in there. It's a quick way to replicate configuration files — put whatever is useful to you in there.

Comment: @Roger Mortis: I keep my `.emacs` file in there, as well as my `gpg`, `ssh`, and `zsh` config (not key!) files, and some other miscellaneous configurations in there. Very useful!